# Linker error reference to function not found

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile, linker-errors

Can someone let me know what the problem might be here? It seems the linker can not find the `min` function although it should be able to find it in `def.o`.

[image: emacs screen showing all the files]

Comment: templates must be defined in header files (*unless explicitly instantiated)

Comment: @PiotrS. yes when I move the definition to header it works. why is so?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12574417/1505939) for explanation and resolution. I have closed the question as a duplicate of the monster "undefined reference" article, but that link is the specific part of the answer relative to your problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/3953764